# Weird Bouncing Issue

Tags: dither, video-games

I was bouncing some sound effects for a project today and they were peaking in the high yellows, below 0. When I played the rendered files on my computer and in-game they sounded incredibly soft. I can't figure out why this would happen. If I raised the gain of anything it'd clip. Do you guys think it's possibly a dithering issue (I went from 24 to 16)? I'm using Reaper as my DAW. Haven't had these issues with PT. I feel like I'm overlooking something really simple.

Do you guys have any thoughts?

Thanks!

-CS

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's a dithering issue (which for the most part only affects the lower end of you dynamic range). What troubleshooting have you done so far?

Are your speakers calibrated? Are you using different speakers between your DAW and game engine? Have you tested out other files (not from Reaper), both in the DAW and on your computer/game engine? Have you reimported the files to your session to see if they behave similar to the original mix there? Have you checked the frequency content (spectral plot) of the bounced file to see if anything is lost?

There are plenty of people here who can probably point you in the right direction, but it's a little hard for us to help you troubleshoot if we don't know what you've done so far. Results of those tests help too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a driver thing? If you're on windows, and you use ASIO in Reaper but the standard Windows Sound output when playing back the bounces, it could be that the Windows volume control is just set very low.

And as @Shaun says, it makes sense to check other files and provide a little more info.